# Regex to Match Valid Variable Pattern

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a string s.  I want to write a function using a regular expression which returns True if s has the following characteristics.

1. ignore the leading whitespace.
2. after step 1, s can start with any of the following a-z, A-Z, or _
3. After the 1st character s can have 0 or more of the following a-z, A-Z, 0-9,  and/or _
4. s can have 1 or more trailing whitespace characters.

I have tried the solution suggested below where am I going wrong?

```
import re
def test_s(s):
     return bool(re.search("[A-Za-z_\s]{1}[A-Za-z0-9_]*[\s]*$",s))
```

Update:
I tried the solution below (It fails to capture my last 2 test cases):

CASE: return bool(re.search(r'\s*[A-Za-z_]\w*\s*', s))

```
TESTLIST = ['__This_Is_a_StringThatShouldWork' , '     SoIsThis1    ' , '4getaboutThis1', '7his_ShouldReturnFalse']]
for s in TESTLIST:
    print(is_var(s))
```

[Out]

```
True
True
True (Should be False)
True (Should be False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re
def test_s(s):
    return bool(re.search(r'\s*[A-Za-z_]\w*\s*', s))
```

Comment: one or more ending whitespaces, as he said

Comment: can have, not does have.  there is a difference

Comment: James:  I updated my comments based on your suggestion.  Any idea why the last two examples of s return True instead of False?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work.

```
import re

def test_s(s):
    return bool(re.match("\s+[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\s+", s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
[a-zA-Z_]\w*\s+
```